# Blackberry:How to add ChoiceGroup in VerticalFieldManager?

Tags: blackberry

I am having a VerticalFieldManager in my application home screen code and adding many fields into it. I would like to add Radio button (which is ChoiceGroup in BB) also into the screen. For that, i am adding ChoiceGroup code lines and trying to add to vertical manager like vfm.add(mChoices), but it is giving compilation error at this place as ....ui.Manager cannot be applied to ....lcdui.ChoiceGroup. Can't i add ChoiceGroup into Vertical Manager. If i use VerticalManager and adding many fields and would like to add Radio button also into it, How do i do that?

Pleaes give your advise.

Thanks.

Comment: I resolved it by using RadioButtonGroup and RadioButtonField. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to Manager only **net.rim.device.api.ui.Field** and it's inheritors

**javax.microedition.lcdui** are not allowed here.

Use **net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ChoiceField**

or
**net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RadioButtonField**

or create your own Fields inheritor